# Проблема python и poplib с получением писем

Tags: python, pop3

Привет. Использую для чтения писем с почты на gmail.com либу poplib. Вот код:

```
import poplib  
import time  
from email.Parser import Parser  
parser = Parser()   
server = poplib.POP3_SSL("pop.gmail.com")  
server.set_debuglevel(1)    
print server.user("you@gmail.com")  
print server.pass_("your-pass")  
server.retr(server.stat()[0])[1]  
server.quit()
```

В результате каким-то образом после выполнения данного скрипта кол-во сообщений уменьшается, то есть я не могу перечитать данное сообщение повторно. Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем проблема? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

server.repr() - это не баг, это реализация POP-протокола. Ваши сообщения не уменьшаются - они просто загружаются, а на сервере удаляются. Это нормальное поведение клиента POP - "забрать" почту. А у вас в почтовых клиентах просто стоит галочка вроде "не удалять сообщения автоматически", что реализовано в библиотеке, по-видимому, как server.top().
Если вы хотите просто читать сообщения и хранить их на сервере, используйте IMAP. Он более приспособлен для таких действий. Тем более, что вы используете Gmail:)

Comment: Но ведь когда я захожу напрямую на gmail.com через браузер, у данных сообщений не меняется вообще никаких атрибутов (удалено и т.п.), в корзине тоже пусто (вкладочка удалены), то есть сообщения я не вижу только в том случае, когда делаю запрос через питон. Или может у сообщения есть какие-либо свойства не отображаемые ни в браузере, ни в почтовых клиентах?  

Comment: Не совсем понял повторный вопрос, я вроде бы полностью ответил:) Как я понял, через server.top() ничего не пропадает, или я не прав?  
В любом случае, повторюсь, с gmail'ом лучше работать через IMAP, он под это "заточен". Или РОР3 критичен?

Comment: не то чтобы очень критичен, но в общем да. А насчет своего вопроса, я не совсем понял насчет удаления сообщений, ведь браузер по идее показывает только те сообщения, которые хранятся на сервере? или я не прав? Ведь когда я просматриваю почту через браузер, причем любой, у меня все сообщения остались.

Comment: Веб-интерфейс у gmail работает через IMAP. Это значит, при заходе он получает заголовки сообщений, если выбрано конкретное письмо - то тело письма, без всяких удалений.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял, я думал там тоже через pop3 протокол все работает...

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел выход... Использую вместо функции server.repr() - server.top(), с помощью которой также можно получить тело и тему письма, и оно не пропадает. Правда с багом в repr() я так и разобрался, если кто знает подскажите в чем проблема? P.S. В браузере и других mail и Mozilla ThunderBird статус сообщений не меняется и все они остаются на месте.